# how to make sharp black white edge

Tags: gimp

How can I make black colour tone pixels completely black. I want to make this on whole raster. I want to do this in Gimp.

[image: graphics sample]

Comment: Perhaps you could try [Burn tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-dodge-burn.html) with `Range: Highlights`

Comment: You can also select by color, sharpen the selection (Select -> Sharpen), fill the whole area.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not solved yet, use the Threshold tool in Colors tab. Adjust slider to achieve desired result.

[image]